# MongoDB: Find and then modify the resulting object

Tags: mongodb

is it possible in MongoDB to find some objects that match a query and then to modify the result without modifying the persistent data?

For example, let

```
students = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 25 }, 
  { name: "Bob",  age: 22 }, 
  { name: "Carol", age: 19 }, 
  { name: "Dave", age: 18}
]
```

Now, I want to query all students that are younger than 20 and in the search result, I just want to replace "age: X" with "under20: 1" resulting in the following:

```
result = [
  { name: "Carol", under20: 1 }, 
  { name: "Dave", under20: 1}
]
```

without changing anything in the database.

Sure, it is possible to get the result and then call a forEach on it, but that sounds so inefficient because I have to rerun every object again, so I'm searching for an alternative. Or is there no one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use an aggregation pipline with a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) followed by a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
db.students.aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: { age: { $lt: 20 } }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: false,
            name: true,
            under20: { $literal: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

The `$literal: 1` is required as just using `under20: 1` is the same as `under20: true`, requesting that field `under20` be included in the result: which would fail as `under20` does not exist in the document produced by the `match`.

Or to return all documents in students and conditionally generate the value for `under20` a possible solution would be to use [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
db.students.aggregate(
[
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: false,
            name: true,
            under20:
            {
                $cond: { if: { $lt: [ "$age", 20 ] }, then: 1, else: 0 }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot! Probably there is also a possibility to calculate the value of under20 like under20 = 1 if age < 20 and 0 otherwise (?)

Comment: @Green, see [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! :)

Comment: Another problem: Assume, some students now have an array "courses". In that one are stored some objects like {name: "Java", credits: 5}. Not every student has such an array.
Now, I want to output all students with a flag whether they participate in the course "Java", like [{name: "Alice", participant: 1}, {name: "Bob", participant: 0}, ...]. Is there a simple solution? 
I've been searching some time, but haven't found any appropriate solution yet.

Comment: @Green, better asking a new question for this. It will get more attention and may help others seeking a solution to a similar problem.